# How to know which element is stale in Protractor?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver

I would like to know how to print **which** element Protractor is complaining of. I understand why elements can be stale but Protractor/WebDriver could give more info on it. Is there a debug/info mode?

```
  Message:
    Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.4 x86_64)
  Stack:
    StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.4 x86_64)
```

(long stack trace omitted)

Comment: that maybe actually a feature request on protractor's github page